# Power series for $2^x$ bypassing $e^x$?

Tags: power-series, taylor-expansion

Is it possible to create a power series for $2^x$ that's always convergent, and where the coefficients are all fractional (that is, bypassing the conversion of $2^x$ to $e^{x\log{2}}$)?

That is, $2^x=\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}c_j x^j$, $\forall$ $x$, where the $c_j$ are fractional.

Please take kindly to this question, I'm a newbie.

Comment: It's not really clear exactly what you're asking..

Comment: @Antinous I reworded the post, have a look.

Comment: Such a series is necessarily the Maclaurin series for $2^x,$ and it doesn't have rational coefficients.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not possible. This would only be possible if $\ln{(2)}$ was rational - which it is not. The method of finding this series expansion can be done avoiding the aforementioned identity by evaluating the function at each of its $n$th derivatives.
$$f(0)=2^0=1$$
$$f'(0)=\ln{(2)}\times2^0=\ln{(2)}$$
$$...$$
$$f^{(n)}(0)=\ln^n{(2)}$$
$$f(x)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{f^{(k)}(0)x^k}{k!}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{\ln^k{(2)}x^k}{k!}=1+\frac{\ln{(2)}x}{1!}+\frac{\ln^2{(2)}x^2}{2!}+...$$

Comment: I pondered about it and came to the conclusion it's really impossible. Thanks for the insight.